# Python 2.7. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7

I'm learning python and want to know how I can fix this error. P.S. I've seen other questions and I did not understand much. thank you

```
A=12
B=14
C=23
E1=input( "num?" )
x,y,z=raw_input(" How +x -y -z? " )
x1=((E1/3)*2)+x
y1=(E1/3)-y
z1=(E1/3)-z
print x, x1, y, y1, z, z1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you used the input() function : It will return a string (character). You try to add some integers to a string, which makes python angry... 
Try to cast your string into integer :

```
E1 = int(input("..."))
```

Comment: num? 12 Vieni + xyz? File ABC "<string>", La Linea 6, in <module> TypeError: tipo operando non supportato (s) per +: 'int' e 'str'. mi dà questo errore

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the value that you are obtaining from the user such as E1 is in the form of string . So you better parse the string to integer before performing addition operation. I would suggest you to use this

E1 = int(input("num?"))

This might help you :)

Comment: num? 12 Vieni + xyz? File ABC "<string>", La Linea 6, in <module> TypeError: tipo operando non supportato (s) per +: 'int' e 'str'. mi dà questo errore

Comment: La risposta di Anton risolve una chiamata `raw_input`, ma ci sono altri tre. È inoltre necessario convertire `x`, `y` e `z`, come `x = int (x)`, `y = int(y)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

daioni .. The same mistake you are doing while getting the values of x,y,z through x,y,z=raw_input(" How +x -y -z? " ).. It again returns string value to you.. So just convert the string to integer . I will again post the code below

```
import numpy
A=12
B=14
C=23
E1=input( "num?" )
x,y,z=raw_input(" How +x -y -z? " )
x=int(x)
y=int(y)
z=int(z)
x1=((E1/3)*2)+x
y1=(E1/3)-y
z1=(E1/3)-z
print x, x1, y, y1, z, z1
```

[image: This is the Output I've got.]

Comment: The Problem That the unknowns x y z I have to associate the letters (A , B , C ) Why do I have to repeat THIS operations Change of Literature type sequence ( or BCA CBA etc .. ) . L ' idea would be eg . num ? 20  B = x = 14 C = y = 23 A = z = 12 then print B 27.3 . C 16.3 A 5.3

Answer (score 0):

```
E1= int ( input ( " num? " ))

x=input(" come +x?int ")
x2=raw_input(" come +x?str ")
y=input(" come -y?int ")
y2=raw_input(" come -y?str ")
z=input(" come -z?int ")
z2=raw_input(" come -z?str ")
x2=str(x2)
y2=str(y2)
z2=str(z2)

x1=((E1/3)*2)+(x)
y1=y-(E1/3)
z1=z-(E1/3)

print x2, x1, y2, y1, z2, z1
```

I solved and thank you for the answer, I was not able to make the script less cumbersome than that. If you have any suggestions?